# How to have "Find in Files" results automatically expanded

Tags: delphi

Simple question, (Easy points!)

In Delphi 2010 (with updates 4 and 5)  "Find in Files" shows the results with the tree closed for each file. I have to click on a plus-sign to open each file's results.

I know there's a way to configure the IDE to automatically show the results with all the trees open, but for some reason (fatigue on my part?) I'm unable to find where to set that option.

Tom

Edit on year later: I re-asked this question here: [Auto-expanding the results of "Find in Files" int the Messages windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286525/auto-expanding-the-results-of-find-in-files-int-the-messages-windows) and got a good answer:

```
 "[Use the] Group results by file" checkbox on the Find In Files dialog.
```

Somehow I'd overlooked that!  I'm posting this edit so that other readers in the future find it here.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612721/how-to-auto-expand-all-ttreeview-nodes

Comment: @mozillanerd: that's for when you use a tree in your own code. Robert is asking about the trees in the IDE... Unless you want him to write an IDE expert FullExpand is not going to help him.

Comment: You are correct, I missed the last paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find anything like what you are asking about, in the Options. Perhaps you confused that with something else, but maybe I overlooked the option (too).

Anyway, there's a keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>, to automatically expand all the tree items in the Message box tree view (when it is focused). Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad -</kbd> collapses them all.

Comment: what is grey+ ? Is that the one on the numpad?

Comment: Thanks, Andriy!  Nice tip.  I'm almost certain that on a previous installation of Delphi 2010 that I used, there was a way to force this to happen automatically. Meanwhile, I'll use your tip and hope that someone else posts here with a way to make it automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question; but I was often frustrated by this, until I found the excellent *Grep Search* that is included with [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/download.html)

It includes an option to 'Expand all matches after searching'. It also fixes many other shortcomings with the Delphi 'Find in Files'. I highly recommend it.