# Auto-expanding the results of "Find in Files" int the Messages windows

Tags: delphi

Simple question, (Easy points!)

In Delphi 2010 (with updates 4 and 5) "Find in Files" shows the results with the tree closed for each file. I have to click on a plus-sign to open each file's results.

I know there's a way to configure the IDE to automatically show the results with all the trees open, but for some reason (fatigue on my part?) I'm unable to find where to set that option in spite of repeated explorations of the Tools, Options screen.

I asked this question 11 months ago:
[How to have "Find in Files" results automatically expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142600/how-to-have-find-in-files-results-automatically-expanded) and got an answer that supplied a hot-key to open the tree, but no automatic opening.

But now, somehow, in XE2 on one of my machines, search results are now opening expanded. So I *know* it's possible. (And, probably, I configured it that way last year!)  But I can't figure out how to do it on my other development machine. The only IDE add-in I'm using is DDevExtensions, so it's not that the one machine is using GEExperts or something to do searches. Clearly, there's an intrinsic option in XE2 to do this. What is it?  :-)

Comment: What is the setting of the "Group results by file" checkbox on the Find In Files dialog?

Comment: <blush>  Of course that's the problem. Somehow I was stuck thinking the option for this was related to the messages tab, not the dialog box itself, David.  If you care to post an answer, I'll give you the points.  Thanks again for all your answers here on StackOverlow, both the easy ones like this, and the not-so-easy ones that you answer. You (and others here) constantly amaze me with your breadth of knowledge and your willingness to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you have un-checked "Group results by file" on
the Find In Files dialog. This puts all the results into the output window with no hierarchy at all. It's not that the tree is auto expanded, rather there is no tree at all!